# Laravel Eloquent Limit in Relation that has Sub Relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have hasmany relation from category to contents, and I want limitation 4 content for each category.

I would like to limit the result of relation **contents** that has sub relation to **languages**

My Code

```
Category::with(['contents.languages' => function($query){
        $query->limit(4);
    }])
        ->get();
```

But I see in log the limit works on **languages** relation, not contents, that I wanted is limit on **contents**

Comment: please clear your question with more details.

Comment: Try putting limit inside your relationship

Comment: @ChiragPatel updated, hope you understand

Comment: @afsalc I have sub relation contents.languages, when I put limit inside of those relation, it works on languages only, not contents

Comment: Did you put in language relation ie in Content Model class , language function()

Comment: @afsalc yes, function languages() hasmany

Comment: What about Category model did you put in contents relation

Comment: @afsalc yes I did it, categories has many contents, in contents has many languages

Comment: Could you post your category model class here

Comment: @afsalc I dont understand what you mean

Comment: Look at tpojka answer

Comment: @afsalc I just try that before, and the result is only get 4 contents for all categories, not for each categories

Comment: And why don't you try to exclude `.languages` part from code you posted: having contents you can get languages over those if relation is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take() and limit() functions will not work with eager loading if you retrieve parent model more than one using get().

So you have to do another way,

```
$categories = Category::with('contents')->get();
```

After retrieving `$categories`, you can do foreach loop like below,

```
$contents = [];
foreach($categories as $category){
   $category->limitedContents = $category->contents()->with('languages')->limit(4);
}
```

And by doing this you will get 4 contents per category in all categories with **`limitedContents`**.

> Note: Here I used name as 'limitedContents' because you have already defined **contents** relationship.

Comment: oh thanks, I think your statement is correct, but if I use your code, It will get all relation in backend and maybe will makes heavy load if I have lots of contents data, get all categories only, and then looping for finding the contents with limitation maybe the best way to optimize

Comment: yeah it will take little more time then eager loading but we get the best result with this :)

Comment: I had to add ->get() after the limit(4)

Answer (score 1):

This question is basically something akin to [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

As far as I can see there's not much choice but to perform N+1 queries. You can achieve this by doing:

```
  $categories = Category::get(); 
  $categories->each(function ($category) {
     $category->load([ 'contents' => function ($q) {
             return $q->limit(4);
     }, 'contents.languages']);
  });
```

Can we do better? I doubt it doubtful, though I am open to ideas. While we can optimise this to send a less queries to the database, the database internally will still need to compute the N+1 queries.

Comment: not working, the contents just showing 4, I have hasmany relation between categories and contents, I want limit 4 content for each categories

Comment: Do you mean that contents is just showing the number 4?

Comment: I mean 4 items, I have many category and hasmany contents, I want to get all categories but only 4 content for each category

Comment: You just said that you wanted to get 4 contents for each category and you are getting 4 contents for each category. What's not working?

Comment: It just showing 4 contents for all category, not for each category.
in log I see this:
select * from `content` where `content`.`category_id` in ('2', '3') limit 4

Comment: I thought it was possible but it probably isn't with a single query eager load query. It might be but I don't really know how. At any rate this update should work but it will do N+1 queries

Answer (score 1):

This also works

```
foreach(Category::with('contents')->get() as $category)
   {
        foreach($category->contents->take(4) as $content)
        {
            $languages = $content->with('languages')->get();
            foreach($languages as $language)
             {
                //your code
             }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
Category::with(['contents.languages'])->limit(4)->get();
```

Comment: it will limit in category, not contents

Answer (score 0):

You could set additional method in `Category` model and make a call with that one:

```
public function contentsTake4()  
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Content')->limit(4);
}
```

Then you would call it in controller as :

```
Category::with('contentsTake4.products')->get();
```

Comment: I just try this before, and the result is only get 4 contents for all categories, not for each categories

Comment: mysql log is like this, select * from content where content.category_id in ('2', '3') limit 4; it will showing only 4 contents for category id 2 and 3, that I want is 4 contents limit for each category (2 and 3)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Category::with([
   'contents' => function($q) { $q->limit(4); },
   'contents.languages'
])->get();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Not working, it will limit the category,  not contents