# Sub query with eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have category table with is_featured column. now I want o select featured categories with 3 product (limit 3 or every featured category). I tried with following code but getting only 3 product from first featured category.

```
$categories = Category::where('is_featured', true)->with('products', function ($query){
        $query->take(3);
    })->get();
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dub: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731582/laravel-eloquent-limit-in-relation-that-has-sub-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like by default its not supported Eager-loading with a limit

To solve this problem you can install following library

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

and use following trait in both the model

```
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
```

if you are looking for without library then

Ref:[Laravel Eloquent limit results for relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097559/laravel-eloquent-limit-results-for-relationship)

Ref:Eager-loading with a limit on collection only loads for last element in collection

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014